# I can't get fail2ban working on Debian 12

Tags: linux, debian

I'm trying to get fail2ban working on my Debian 12 system and I keep running into troubles.

I started by installing fail2ban with this:

```
sudo apt-get install fail2ban
```

Which was successful with the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
fail2ban is already the newest version (1.0.2-2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
   libslirp0 pigz slirp4netns
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 71 not upgraded.
```

I then enable fail2ban with the following:

```
sudo systemctl enable fail2ban
```

Giving me the successful output of:

```
Synchronizing state of fail2ban.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/.systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable fail2ban
```

I then try to start the service with:

```
sudo systemctl start fail2ban
```

Which is successful. However when I try to check the status of the fail2ban service I'm greeted with the following output:

```
sudo systemctl status fail2ban: 
× fail2ban.service - Fail2Ban Service
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fail2ban.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-02-14 12:48:29 EST; 1min 49s ago
 Duration: 108ms
     Docs: man:fail2ban(1)
  Process: 9493 ExecStart=/usr/bin/fail2ban-server -xf start (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
 Main PID: 9493 (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
    CPU: 103ms
Feb 14 12:48:29 [REDACTED HOSTNAME] systemd[1]: Started fail2ban.service - Fail2Ban Service.
Feb 14 12:48:29 [REDACTED HOSTNAME] fail2ban-server[9493]: 2024-02-14 12:48:29,128 fail2ban.configreader   [9493]: WARNING 'allowipv6' not defined in 'Definition'. Using default one: 'auto'>
Feb 14 12:48:29 [REDACTED HOSTNAME] fail2ban-server[9493]: 2024-02-14 12:48:29,140 fail2ban                [9493]: ERROR   Failed during configuration: Have not found any log file for sshd jail>
Feb 14 12:48:29 [REDACTED HOSTNAME] fail2ban-server[9493]: 2024-02-14 12:48:29,145 fail2ban                [9493]: ERROR   Async configuration of server failed
Feb 14 12:48:29 [REDACTED HOSTNAME] systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
Feb 14 12:48:29 [REDACTED HOSTNAME] systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I've seen people online talking about modifying the SSHD jail file but there's so many mixed answers I just don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

On Debian 12 there are a couple of things you have to do to make it work.

First go to the config file:

```
nano /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

And add this `backend=systemd` before `enabled=true` to make it look like that for example:

```
[sshd]
backend=systemd
enabled = true
port = ssh
filter = sshd
logpath = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 3
```

And then save and run this command:

```
apt install python3-systemd
```

Now restart fail2ban:

```
systemctl restart fail2ban
```

And check the status, it should be working.

Comment: I searched for the jail.local file and I actually don't have it. 
When I list all the contents of the /etc/fail2ban folder it returns: 

.
..
action.d
fail2ban.conf
fail2ban.d
filter.d
jail.conf
jail.d
paths-arch.conf
paths-common.conf
paths-debian.conf
paths-opensuse.conf

Could I search the interwebs and manually add that file? Maybe that's what's missing.

Comment: You have to create it using this command "sudo cp /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/jail.local"